# Extract a subset of XML file using XSL and change one node

Tags: xslt

I have this XML file

```
<Person>
   <Name>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
   </Name>
   <Address>
      <Street>Grand Street</Street>
      <ZIP>1002</ZIP>
      <City>New York</City>
   </Address>
</Person>
```

I want to have that output:

```
<Address>
   <Street>Changed Street</Street>
   <ZIP>1002</ZIP>
   <City>New York</City>
</Address>
```

So in fact I want to extract the -Node plus change a single node

I tried the following xsl, but it only extracted the Address-Node without changed the value of the Street-Node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"  indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Person/Address">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/Address/Street">
      <Street>Changed Street</Street>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone know a possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Try starting off with the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you only need to worry about having templates for the part of the document you want to change.

So, to select only the `Address` element, you could do it with this template:

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Address" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of `xsl:apply-templates`, instead of `xsl:copy-of` as this will allow templates to be applied to any descendant nodes.

To change the address node, have a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Address/Street">
   <Street>Changed Street</Street>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the lack of `/` at the state. `/` at the start of the expression represents the document node, so `/Address` would only match the address if it was the root element of the document.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Person">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Address" />
    </xsl:template>
    
   <xsl:template match="Address/Street">
      <Street>Changed Street</Street>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your current XSLT seems to suggest you want to ignore attributes (not that your XML sample has attributes), but if you did really want to ignore them, change the last template to this instead...

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```